# convert comma separated array of element to integer value in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have got one array with string value which contain comma separator.

```
const array = [
  "65,755.47",
  0,
  null,
  0,
]
```

i want to remove the string from the value and other value remain constant in the array.

so the the output should be:--

```
const array = [
  65,755.47,
  0,
  null,
  0,
]
```

How can i achieve this?Thanks!!

Comment: As you removed my edit I think you don't understand what you did here. `65,755.47,` are two separate numbers because they are comma-separated. That is how this works. The whitespace or newline does **not** matter.

Comment: @Randy i want the output like this that i have mentioned...the value should be in comma separated.

Comment: @Ashishgoodluckchuck numbers in javascript cannot be "comma separated", you have to explicitly convert it to a string with commas if you want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a flat map

```js
const arr = ["65,755.47", 0, null, 0];

const res = arr.flatMap((el) => {
  if (typeof el === "string") {
    return el.split(",").map((n) => +n);
  }
  return el;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```js
const data = [
  "65,755.47",
  0,
  null,
  0,
]


const result1 = data.map(v => typeof v === 'string'?v.split(',').map(Number): v)
const result2 = data.flatMap(v => typeof v === 'string'?v.split(',').map(Number): v)

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: This is not working if you have another number than 0

Comment: @mgm793 you're right I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Given the array

```
const array = ["65755.47", 0, null, 0];
```

You can run this

```
const converted = array.map((item) => item ? Number(item) : item)
```

Or alternatively, you have strings with comma

```
const array2 = ["65,755.47", 0, null, 0];
```

you should remove commas before converting the item

```
const converted2 = array2.map((item) =>
  typeof item === "string" ? parseFloat(item.replace(/,/g, "")) : item
);
```

Comment: Removing the comma gives a completely different result than desired.

Comment: but i want comma over the values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doSomething() {
  const input = ["65, 755.47", 0, null, 0];
  input[0] = input[0].split(",").map((num) => parseFloat(num));
  return input.flat()
}
console.log(doSomething())
```

This should work if your input array does not change over time.

Comment: Although this seems to work, it does not scale to an array with more strings. Usually in solutions like this we work in algorithms instead of manually finding the string with hard-coded mapping on the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething() {
    let x = [];
    const input = ["65, 755.47, 45", 0, null, 0];
    input.forEach(element => {
        // check is string
        if (typeof element === 'string' || element instanceof String) {
            x = x.concat(element.split(',').map((e)=>parseFloat(e)));
        } else {
            x.push(element);
        }
    })
    return x;
  }
console.log(doSomething())
```

it' oke